# Search for records with apostrophe

Tags: mysql

I am trying to search the database for a keyword like Obrien and the results should return all the records with O'Brien too. I have tried with fulltext search of MySql. The problem with it is the resultset can cntainn only 1 record  but fulltext feature requires the resultset to contain atlest 3 records or 50% of the matched results.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Why not just ignore the other results? Also, how can you be sure that the first result is the one you're looking for?

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear. What I meant is, the results can contain only 1 match, and this is where mysql fulltext search does not show this single match

Answer (score 0):

could you do something like:

```
REPLACE(name,'''','')
```

I tested it:

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(10)
SELECT @name = 'O''brien'

SELECT @name as "pre", REPLACE(@name, '''', '') as "post"
```

and it game me O'brien for the pre column and Obrien for the post column.

edit after response from OP:
try this

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM table
WHERE REPLACE(name, '''', '') = REPLACE(searchString, '''', '')
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick response. I tried this solution but what
I am looking for is to enter the search string as "Obrien" and expect the results to show the records with "Obrien" and "O'Brien".

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your response. Truly appreciate your help. I tried this and it worked for me. I got this solution from this site itself.

Title : Apostrophes and SQL Server FT search

the last solution as suggested by "Alistair Knock" which is

SELECT surname
FROM table
WHERE surname LIKE '%value%'
OR REPLACE(surname,'''','') LIKE '%value%'

This works even when FT is not enabled.

Thanks you everyone. Hope this helps somebody.